Mongo DB connection using pymongo in Python not responding or hangs intermittently
I am connecting to mongoDB using pymongo MongoClient in python.
MongoDB ping command and other operations hangs or gets stuck without responding.
This issue occurs intermittently only.
In below code block the first print statement works but second print statement never gets printed since the ping command is not responding.
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient(mongo_url)
print("Starting to ping")
ping = client.admin.command('ping')
print("Completed ping")

Note:
MongoClient version is 3.10
MongoDB Server version is 4.2
Python version is 3.10
Tried updating code as below but we are not getting any errors or exceptions and no response for infinite time.
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient(mongo_url, waitQueueTimeoutMS=5000, socketTimeoutMS=5000,
                     serverSelectionTimeoutMS=5000, connectTimeoutMS=5000, maxPoolSize=100)
try:
    print("Starting to ping")
    ping = client.admin.command('ping')
    print("Completed ping")
except ConnectionFailure:
    print("Server not available")
except pymongo.errors.PyMongoError as e:
    print("Pymongo error: " + str(e))
except Exception as exc:
    print("Exception: " + str(exc))


Upgrade your pymongo to the latest version (currently 4.8.0)
